Ubuntu Tiling Assistant not available after LTS upgrade from 22 to 24.4.1
After upgrading from 22 LTS to 24 LTS, I do not seem to have the Ubuntu Tiling Manager. In fact, it doesn't even show up in the Ubuntu Desktop settings page. I tried installing Tiling Assistant directly, and while that will give me window tiling, the Ubuntu Tiling Manager settings don't show up. I'm assuming it's a slightly different version, and I'd like to use the one that's supposed to be included with 24.4.1 LTS.
What might I be able to do to make this show up on my system?


So the solution ended up being to install a specifically named package, which I didn't know.
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant followed by a reboot ended up being the secret sauce here.
Thanks to this reddit post for the solution. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1g2wk1j/system_extension_tiling_assistant_2404/
